# How to create unique ID of a specific column based on defined combinations from a dictionary

Tags: pyspark

I want create a unique ID based on a column of a data frame which has multiple groups.  In a dictionary I have defined an ID for each group. How do I add this ID to this data frame based on the dictionary that I have created.

Below is the sample data and the code

```
conf_1 = {
    'cat':{'1': ['A_10','A_13'], 
           '2': ['B_8','B_4'],
           '3': ['A_11','A_13'],
               },
}

testlist = [
             {"cat":"A_10","val":10}, 
             {"cat":"A_13","val":11}, 
             {"cat":"B_8","val":12},
             {"cat":"B_4","val":14},
            {"cat":"A_11","val":9},
            {"cat":"A_13","val":16},
]

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(testlist)

df = []
for i in conf_1['cat']:
  testlist.filter((f.col('cat').isin(i)) | (f.col('cat').isin(i)))
  .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

The final output should look like below

[image]

Comment: how come A_13 has both id as 1 and 3? Also can the dictionary have more keys matching the column names of the spark df?

Comment: Yea the ID should be unique for the combination rather than specific category like A_13. on the second question yea the dictionary can have more keys

Comment: yea the same combination will be added to the dictionary. There wont be any combination which the data frame will have and not in the dictionary